# Hey, if I use "Mobile Tethering" and share a network with my computer, will the network admin be able to see my activity on my computer?

Tags: samsung, tethering

if I use "Mobile Tethering" and share a network with my computer, will the network admin be able to see my activity on my computer?? If the Admin can see my activity, is there any other ways to "hide" my activity on my computer??

Comment: Pretty off topic as this isn't really an Android related question, but the answer is maybe... depends on what they monitoring and how they are doing it. If this is a corporate computer on a domain, there isn't much you can do to "hide" your activity, they can install or monitor anything in any way they chose. From a network admin standpoint, I tell people there is NOTHING you can do on a corporate PC that I cannot detect or monitor, and that is largely true. There are certainly ways, but teaching someone how to violate a corporate security policy isn't for this site/group.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Its possible to do so. Here, I am adding a link that can guide you to the process. I am sure that will help you out in the pursuit of getting your query answered without any bias.
https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-check-what-people-are-surfing-using-my-WiFi